# What kind of Chinese visa do I need to visit Chinese friend in China?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, china, proof-of-accommodation

I'm an Indian citizen and planning to travel to China to visit my Chinese friend. My friend is currently in the US doing MS and will be going home to China in December for vacation. So I'm going at that time to visit him. The plan is to stay at his parent's house for my short stay (one week there).

So should I apply for a normal **L** tourist visa?

Also will it be problematic that I'm staying at his house rather than at a hotel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is perfectly fine to visit a Chinese friend on an L (tourist) visa. To obtain the visa, your friend should write a letter of invitation and send it to you. You should submit it with your visa application.

According to the [visa application instructions](http://in.china-embassy.org/eng/lsfw/qz/t917022.htm), the invitation letter should include:

> The invitation letter should contain:
>
> a. Information on the applicant (full name, gender, date of birth, etc.)
>
> b. Information on the planned visit (arrival and departure dates, place(s) to be visited, etc.)
>
> c. Information on the inviting entity or individual (name, contact telephone number, address, official stamp, signature of the legal representative or the inviting individual)

See the instructions for additional documents that you must provide.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I tell them that I'm staying with the friend at his house, will that be held against me? Will I be asked to give docs to prove relationship or something?

Comment: Why would that be held against you? And the documents you need are shown in the instructions.

Comment: I just read somewhere that it will be easier to prove with hotel registration; so asked.
By the way, can my friend just scan and email me the invitation letter which I can print and submit? The agency I approached here told me that he will have to courier me the original letter and I need to submit that. But when I applied for Canadian and Shengen visas (business) previously, I just printed out the digital letters and submitted them and it worked.

Comment: @Sparky I doubt that even an email would be a problem, provided it contained all of the required information. I would only recommend that it be written in Chinese. :)